# WinRM with remote exec connection time out- Azure Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-powershell, terraform-provider-azure

```
connection {
  type = "winrm"
  user = "testadmin"
  password = "Password1234!"
  host = azurerm_public_ip.example.ip_address
```

}
provisioner "remote-exec" {

```
 script = "C:\\Proj\\Fali\\vm\\DC.ps1" 
}
```

I have opened all  the ports

```
direction                  = "Inbound"
access                     = "Allow"
protocol                   = "Tcp"
source_port_range          = "*"
destination_port_range     = "*"
source_address_prefix      = "*"
destination_address_prefix = "*"
```

Connection timeout during running a PS Script,
Mentioned is code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the workaround to resolve the above issue;

You can use the below format in your `example.tf` file by provisioning the file name and provide the timeout value to it .

```
connection {
    host     = azurerm_public_ip.win_pubip.fqdn
    type     = "winrm"
    port     = 5985
    https    = false
    timeout  = "2m"
    user     = var.username
    password = var.password
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "files/yourfile.ps1"
    destination = "c:/terraform/yourfile.ps1"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass c:\\terraform\\yourfile.ps1",
    ]
```

*For complete information  how to provision and execute the configuration script,please refer this*

[**`GitHub Sample code`**](https://github.com/jmassardo/Azure-WinRM-Terraform)

And for more information please refer the below links:-

- **SO THREAD**| [***Terraform - Azure Windows VM winrm connection issue***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686807/terraform-azure-windows-vm-winrm-connection-issue?rq=1).

Comment: with azurerm_virtual_machine.main,
│   on main.tf line 147, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main":
│  147:   provisioner "file" {
│
│ timeout - last error: unknown error Post "http://:5985/wsman": dial tcp :5985: connectex: No connection could be made because   
│ the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: Could you please check if the WinRm is successfully setup or not (e.g, enabled certificate)  . Also please refer this  [**SO THREAD**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440481/terraform-provisioner-cannot-winrm-to-new-built-windows-vm-on-azure)&[Blog](https://realworldit.net/archives/89)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to perform the given task is to use OpenSSH instead of WinRM. However, you will need to install the OpenSSH Server on the Windows server and open a port, not necessarily port 22

You can install OpenSSH server using windows-capability.
Execute below command in elevated PowerShell:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Reference: [Get started with OpenSSH for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell#install-openssh-for-windows)